# How to install or enable CUDA and cuDNN in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, nvidia-geforce, 23.10

I am trying to enable cuda and cudnn in my ubuntu 23.10, however, the only available cuda toolkit is for Ubuntu 22.04, any suggestions how can I proceed?

Comment: If you are using CUDA 11, the steps is to use GCC 10 during installation. I put the detail steps at here: https://www.yodiw.com/install-cuda-11-on-ubuntu-23-10/

Answer (score 4):

To install CUDA and cuDNN in Ubuntu 23.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

The NVIDIA CUDA Deep Neural Network library (cuDNN) is a GPU-accelerated library of primitives for deep neural networks. cuDNN provides highly tuned implementations for standard routines such as forward and backward convolution, pooling, normalization, and activation layers. cuDNN is part of the NVIDIA Deep Learning SDK.

It's just as good as the software from the NVIDIA website, and much easier to install and (automatically) update.